# Return values based on the sum of array indeces

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to return all values in an array where the row number plus the column number is a multiple of 5.

I feel like I'm close, but I can't seem to get the (i + j) % 5 == 0 part working as a condition.

using:

(i + j) % 5 == 0

I have constructed a random 8 x 9 array using:

arr2 = np.random.normal(size = (8,9), loc=1, scale=0.5)

Comment: Show us the code that is not working. Also describe in what way it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.empty([100,100])
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range(0,len(a[0])):
               if (i+j)%5 == 0:
                 print(i,j,i+j a[i][j])
```

output

```
0 0 0 0.0
0 5 5 0.0
0 10 10 0.0
0 15 15 0.0
0 20 20 0.0
.
. 
.
```

I don't know what you did wrong you have the correct logic. Its a simple loop where you use the index itself as a test rather than than contents at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome thanks. I actually tweaked this a little to get the mean of all values that meet this criteria:

```
def arrmean5 (arr):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        for j in range(0,len(arr[0])):
            if (i+j) % 5 == 0:
                total = total + (arr[i][j])
                count += 1
    return(total/count)
```

I appreciate the help Sam!